# ASP.NET MVC posting with Ajax.BeginForm returns blank view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a page that contains multiple inputs - I'm using Ajax.BeginForm to build a form for each set of inputs.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, HttpMethod = "POST" }))
   { %>
     <input class="smallInput" type="text" name="duration"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Add" />
<% } %>
```

The controller looks like this

```
   [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
   public ActionResult AddExercise(FormCollection form)
   {

       // some save logic...

       return Content(string.Empty);

   }
```

This works - the data is submitted to my controller and is saved.

However, every time this happens my page is replaced by a blank page.  If I explicitly return a View from my Action, that view appears instead.  But I want it to submit the form, leaving my existing page in place as-is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't including the MVC Ajax javascript files in my page.  Adding those includes fixed the problem.

Comment: When you say files, what files are they? I only see http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/2.0/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js on their site for MVC 2 and when I use it I get an error saying `Type` is undefined.

Comment: Nick - this was posted 4 years ago.  I have no idea what specific files were missing anymore.

Comment: jquery-ajax-unobtrusive --> https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/blob/master/src/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the id of the DOM element that you want to be updated:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions() { 
    UpdateTargetId = "someID", 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, 
    HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{ %>
    <input class="smallInput" type="text" name="duration"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
<% } %>
```